# How to set the height of a tableView dynamic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with dynamic cell count. And I am having trouble with the height of the tableview. The tableview does scroll but it doesn't go all the way down to the last cell, it can but I need to do click on the tableview and scroll hard all the way down and when I release the click it will be back.

Here's how I implement it

```
UIInterfaceOrientation newOrientation =  [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if(newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{

    _logoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width/2.3, self.view.bounds.size.height/3)];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2.3, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width - self.view.bounds.size.width/2.3, self.view.bounds.size.height + self.view.bounds.size.height)];


}

else if (newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{

    _logoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/4)];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height/4, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
}
imageView.frame = _logoView.bounds;
[_logoView addSubview:imageView];


self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cells"];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

And when I add another self.view.bounds.height to the height of the tableview in portrait, the tableview get's smaller

Comment: why not use vfl(autolayout)?

Comment: What is that? By the way, i am creating the tableview dynamically

Comment: visual formatting layout of autolayout. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html) @drbj

Comment: its the same as how you create the rect of a view and it will handle the update of it as well.

Comment: Is there a workaround? Except for the vfl

Comment: if you don't use auto layout, set the tableview frame based on tableview content size in - (void)layoutSubviews

Comment: @childrenOurFuture Can you please elaborate it? Sorry, im new on objective c

Comment: Or can you provide a code snippet? I would really appreciate it

Comment: Put the code after self.tableView.reloadData  `CGSize contentSize = self.tableView.contentSize;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentSize.width, contentSize.height);`   I have to say, the code is not good, just for your question, I suggest use auto layout or subclass UITableView and customize it.

Comment: Still having the same issue, the scrollview is not paired with the tableView. I can't scroll all the way down unless I scrolled hard. And once I let go of the click, it will scroll back to the default

Comment: My bad. Fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. My bad. My UITableView height is exceeding. Decreased it's height and it's working properly now